# How to test the quality of a current source design

Tags: mosfet, integrated-circuit, analysis

I have designed a temperature independent and voltage supply independent current source based on the beta-multiplier circuit. So far I have only simulated with temperature change and transient analysis.

My question is: what should I take in consideration to rate how "well" my design works? And how do I conduct these analysis? So far I have only have simulate with temperature change and transient analysis.

Comment: Voltage range and current variation with load range then compare with desired load regulation error tolerance.

Comment: As the thing has to produce a defined output current, it's variation of output current versus anything/everything else. So versus output voltage, versus supply voltage, versus temperature, versus time (drift), versus before and after a transient (self heating), versus component tolerances (manufacturability), versus incident RF, light and magnetic fields (susceptibility to external influences). Not all of these may be important to you, but the first few should be.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of analyses you can make depends on the tools and models that you have at your disposal.

The minimum would be a corner simulation over process, voltage and temperature where all possible combinations are used to determine the variation of the output current.

Ideally also a Monte-Carlo simulation should be made to see the impact of device mismatch on your design. If possible corner simulation and Monte-Carlo simulation should be combined.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. So basically, if I run Monte-Carlo my curent result should show no change?

Comment: No, if it shows no change at all then you MC simulation is not working properly. The variation should be small and within your specification.

Answer (score 0):

Lets see curreent source.  This is what I would want to see in a complete specification: (applies over specified temp range, supply voltage range load )output current range) and specified phase of moon.

- Settablity - how well the commanded current matches the actual.
- Linearity - of this response, over frequency temp, etc
- Stability - drift w/ time temp etc
- output impedance. - ideal sources are infinite over all freequencies
- Noise - how close to quantum shot noise ("noise figure")
- Power dissipation vs die temp for given mount.
- Packaging - plastic, ceramic, lead frame, pinout, SPICE model etc.
- Static discharge tolerance
- Radiation tolerance - neutron flux to cause error out of spec, EMP, gamma
- shock and vibration
- emi (RF susceptibility as well as emission)
- safety (shock, fire, pyro hazard)

Just a few off the top of my head.  probably others specific to the application.
- as pointed out above, buy someone else. chemical suscept.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. How exactly do I measure power dissipation using simulation tool?

Comment: Use an ideal multi[plier, say poly(2) vcvs, run the current through a 1uOhm resistor, mutiply by 1E6, probe volts

Comment: The simulator obviously only goes so far.  Laws of Physics apply everywhere and always.  How many you need is up to your client.